# How to call DLL APIs

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I am attempting to write an application in VC++ version 8. I have a DLL, using dependency walker I got the list of APIs available with DLL.

I am able to load DLL.But when i tried to call some of the APIs in DLL, I will then get this debug error

"Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call.  This is usually a result of calling a function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer declared with a different calling convention."

```
typedef void ( WINAPI *RECEIVE_CALLBACK)int*, int );

typedef void (WINAPI *MYPROC)(RECEIVE_CALLBACK);

     .....
     .....

handleDll = LoadLibraryW((LPCWSTR)L"Example.dll");

ProcAdd = (MYPROC) GetProcAddress(handleDll, "_DLLAPI_Call1@8"); 

(ProcAdd) ( (RECEIVE_CALLBACK) ReceiveFunc);
```

When the last line is executed i am getting the above error. What could be the reason?

Comment: You should almost never cast a function pointer.  Casting the return value from `GetProcAddress` is the only acceptable time.  (To be clear, the cast in the last line of code is either useless or wrong)

Answer (score 4):

Your MYPROC function pointer declaration is wrong.  This function takes two arguments, not one.  You can tell from the @8 part of the name, that says that the argument values require 8 bytes of stack space.  Calling it with one argument, a 4 byte pointer, will always imbalance the stack.

You'll need to fix your MYPROC declaration.

Comment: Assuming this is 32-bit code, you are correct.  And indeed mention of `ESP` in the error message confirms that.

Comment: @BenVoigt: x64 does not use name mangling because it has a single calling convention. So `@8` clearly points to 32-bit code.

Comment: Another thing, you may (if possible) want to consider converting the `_DLLAPI_Call1@8` to a C function using `extern "C"`.  Decorated (C++) functions have the possibility of changing later down the road, and switching it to a C function will undecorate it and force its name to stay the same.

Comment: No, it is not a C++ name decoration.  It is a calling convention decoration, __stdcall, aka WINAPI.  He got that right.